# Multiple first and last non-NA values by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```r
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(
  id = c(rep('Grp 1', 31), rep('Grp 2', 31)),
  date = rep(as.IDate(as.IDate('2020-01-01') : as.IDate('2020-01-31')), 2),
  change = c(rep(NA, 5), rep('yes', 5), rep(NA, 10), rep('yes', 3), rep(NA, 8),
             rep(NA, 2), rep('yes', 8), rep(NA, 8), rep('yes', 5), rep(NA, 8))
)
```

For every group `id` I'd like to filter the first and last `date`s of a series, which is defined by a second column `change` being `yes` (i.e. non-NA). I can do the following, which would provide me with the first and last non-NA row by group. However, the problem is that the series occurs more than once per group.

```r
dt[ !is.na(change),
    .(head(date, 1),
      tail(date, 1)),
    .(id) ]
```

These are the row indices I'd like to have filtered:

```r
dt[c(6,10,21,23,34,41,50,54)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to give a unique group id to each streak identified by an `id` and `change` combination. We can use `rleid` to generate such run-length type ids. Consider something like this

```
dt[,
   gid := rleid(id, change)
][!is.na(change),
  as.list(range(date)),
  by = .(id, gid)
][, 
  gid := NULL
]
```

Note that I also assume that you want the range of dates, not really the first and last elements. Your method will fail if the dates are not in chronological order. Output looks like this

```
      id         V1         V2
1: Grp 1 2020-01-06 2020-01-10
2: Grp 1 2020-01-21 2020-01-23
3: Grp 2 2020-01-03 2020-01-10
4: Grp 2 2020-01-19 2020-01-23
```

`rleid` works like this

```
> rleid(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), c("a", "b", "b", "d", "d"))
[1] 1 2 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dt %>%
     group_by(grp = rleid(id, change), id) %>% 
     filter(!is.na(change)) %>%
     summarise(V1 = min(date, na.rm = TRUE),
               V2 = max(date, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#    grp id    V1         V2        
#  <int> <chr> <date>     <date>    
#1     2 Grp 1 2020-01-06 2020-01-10
#2     4 Grp 1 2020-01-21 2020-01-23
#3     7 Grp 2 2020-01-03 2020-01-10
#4     9 Grp 2 2020-01-19 2020-01-23
```